# Disk issues on reboot

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility

I have a rMBP (Mid 2012) that is having disk issues. When verifying the disk, I get three different errors:

- Incorrect number of file hard links
- Invalid first link in hard link chain
- Invalid directory item count

Rebooting into single user mode and running `fsck -fy` seems to fix these errors, as a subsequent run of `fsck -fy` does not report any errors after the first completes. However, after rebooting, the errors are once again present.

I have also rebooted into Internet Recovery to run Disk Utility and get an error that Disk Utility cannot repair the drive.

The only issue that I have noticed while using my laptop is inability to repartition my hard drive. I fixed this issue once before so I could repartition my hard drive, but do not remember what I did.

The SMART status of my hard drive doesn't indicate any problems, so the only solution I can come to is wiping my drive and reinstalling OS X, although I would rather do that in the fall to do a clean install of El Capitan. Is there anything else that I could do to at least resolve the issue of not being able to repartition my hard drive?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that after a little more research, I was able to recover my issue with a more aggressive `fsck_hfs -drfs /dev/disk0s2` call.